# Identify bad disks which is in OS HW RAID

Tags: centos, raid1

We have servers where a CentOS OS disk is in hardware RAID 1, however we couldn't determine if there was a disk problem until both disks failed.

`smartmontools` seems like it doesn't work well for this purpose on a RAID disk.

Is there a tool or a way to identify the disks that have a problem?

Comment: What RAID vendor?  Please use a utility like `lshw` or `lspci` and post information about it.  The utility to use for RAIDs from a particular vendor may also vary by controller chipset.  In some cases, the specific OS version may be relevant, so please add more of the essential information to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Normally there's a vendor specific utility which could be used to show disks status and request their SMART values. For instance there's a `megacli` [utility](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/MegaCli) for LSI RAID adapters.

Please use the `lspci` output to identify your HW RAID vendor and then look it up in Google.